# Next JS Returned Element Does Not Apply CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, styled-jsx

It seems if I create a function to return a dom element with a className associated, the local style does not get applied e.g;

```
export default function thing(){
    const elem = function(){
        return (<div className="myCss">Hello</div>)
    }
    
    return(
        <>
            { elem() }
            <style jsx>{` .myCss{ color:#f00 } `}</style>
        </>

    )    
}
```

My expectation is that elem() would return an element that would inherit the style associated to the .myCss class. But it doesn't :/

Comment: It seems like your code already working. Cloned code here https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-yisop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [default](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx#why-it-works-like-this) styled-jsx transpiles the stylenames, so your example generates dynamic styles e.g: `.mycss-123` - If you want `.myCss` to be intact, add `global` - Additionally, your template string contains spaces.

This works.

```
<style jsx global>{`.myCss{ color:red }`}</style>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, I've discovered.  Unfortunately, hot reloading works weird with this tag :/